# Download latest version of an extension without installing?

Tags: extension

Also raised in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2635

Download latest version of an extension without installing
Overview

It would be good to be able to download the latest version of an extension without installing it for security reasons.
Current behaviour

1. an extension that was previously installed but since disabled or uninstalled remains present in the extension directory
2. the extensions management ui provides buttons to download and install

Proposed behaviour

1. an extension that was previously installed but since disabled or uninstalled remains present in the extension directory
2. the extensions management ui provides buttons to "download" or to "download and install"

Comments

Of course best practice is to remove any extension which is uninstalled, but disabled extensions are also present in the filesystem. Being able to update extensions that are not installed, improves security as the latest stable code can be downloaded.

My question is if this would indeed the desired solution?